# Ignore property from XML serialization/deserialization in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, asp.net-core-webapi

I've added [XmlIgnore] to ignored property. It's not working.

Model:

```
public class PointOfInterest   // Child model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public int CityId { get; set; }   // Foreign key
    [JsonIgnore]   // Used to avoid circular reference
    [XmlIgnore]
    public City City { get; set; }   // Parent
}
```

Setup application/xml as Accept header:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMvc()   // Add MVC middleware to DI
            .AddMvcOptions(option => option
                    // Add application/xml as Accept Header
                .OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter()))
```

Error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Object graph for type 'WebApiDemo.Models.PointOfInterest' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if references are not tracked. Consider using the DataContractAttribute with the IsReference property set to true.

Comment: The error message says: `Consider using the DataContractAttribute with the IsReference property set to true`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. I added `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` to `PointOfInterest`. Although the cyclic reference errors goes away, but the returned XML is in a weird format.

Comment: I don't think XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter is using XmlIgnoreAttribute and friends. They are used by XmlSerializer which is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message try using `DataContractAttribute` with the `IsReference` setting:

```
Consider using the DataContractAttribute with the IsReference property set to true.
```